# Does fyne support file drag upload?

Tags: drag, fyne

I have a entry and a file selector,at the same time, I want to support automatically binding the file path to the entry when dragging files onto the entry...

```
fileLabel := widget.NewLabel("filePath:")
fileEntry := widget.NewEntry()
fileButton := widget.NewButton("  Open  ", func() {
fd := dialog.NewFileOpen(func(reader fyne.URIReadCloser, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        dialog.ShowError(err, w)
        return
    }
    if reader == nil {
        log.Println("Cancelled")
        return
    }
    fileEntry.SetText(reader.URI().Path())
}, w)
fd.Resize(fyne.NewSize(600, 400))
fd.SetFilter(storage.NewExtensionFileFilter([]string{".xlsx"})) 
fd.Show()
```

})

I looked at Fyne's Draggable interface and it doesn't support it

Comment: The question in your title is answered by your last sentence so what is your real question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in v2.4.0 there was a new API to support accepting items dropped on to a window. Check out `Window.SetOnDropped(func(Position, []URI))` to implement this callback.

The draggable interface is for dragging items around in a user interface, not part of drag and drop.
There is currently no support to drag onto a specific widget - that requires a full drag and drop implementation which is not available.

Comment: Thank you very much. This can already meet my needs